# Figuring out a join between two users excluding where column does not exist for one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Sqlfiddle here:**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c532/6

I have a table (`user_answers`) that holds the answers that users give to questions.  In the sqlfiddle we have data for user 1 and for user 2.  User 1 has answered 5 questions total and user 2 has answered 8 questions total.

**The result I am looking for:**
I want to be able to pull how many questions a user has answered that the other one has also answered.  An example output would be like this: "User 1 has answered 5 out of the 8 questions you have answered".

I have tried joining the tables but it is giving me more results than I was expecting and I hadn't yet specified which users to test in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_answers t1
JOIN user_answers t2 ON t1.uid > t2.uid
AND t1.answer IS NOT NULL
```

And then when I tried to specify users I got no results with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_answers t1
JOIN user_answers t2 ON t1.uid > t2.uid
AND t1.answer IS NOT NULL
AND t1.uid = 1
AND t2.uid = 2
```

I feel like I'm getting closer but could use some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a subquery?

```
 SELECT * FROM user_answers t1
 where t1.uid=1 and t1.quid in 
 (select t2.quid from user_answers t2 where t2.uid=2);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was playing with a subquery, but I was also reading where it might not perform as well as a join. Is a join still possible in this case or is subquery the best method for the results I am looking for?  Cheers.

Comment: You certainly can replace it with a join doing something like this ` SELECT t1.quid FROM user_answers t1 join user_answers t2 on 
 t1.id= t2.id group by t1.quid having count(*) > 1;`. But I would recommend taking a look at this answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577188/473637

Comment: This doesn't remotely answer the question. Where are the question totals for the users? Where is the shared question total?

Answer (score 0):

To find the total number of questions asked by each user, and how many coincided:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct t1.id) user1_total,
  sum(t1.quid = t2.quid) shared_total,
  count(distinct t2.id) user2_total
FROM user_answers t1
CROSS JOIN user_answers t2
WHERE t1.uid=1
AND t2.uid=2
```

Using your data, this returns:

```
USER1_TOTAL SHARED_TOTAL USER2_TOTAL
5           5            7
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c532/40).

Also, any time you can replace a `WHERE ID IN (subquery)` with a `JOIN` you should - the join (virtually) always performs better.